# Google's recommended method of optimising CSS to avoid renderblocking is not working

Tags: css, pagespeed

I'm trying to pass Google's pagespeed tests, and renderblocking is an issue (this is at a client request, so it has to be done). Google's recommended solution is to inline critical CSS (not an option) and then dynamically append the css file to the head tag in javascript at the bottom of the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .blue{color:blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="blue">
  Hello, world!
</div>
<script>
  var cb = function() {
    var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = 'small.css';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(cb);
  else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So a) when I remove the css completely (removing the link tag in the header, and not using any other method), all my js files at the bottom of the html file do not fail the renderblocking test. Everything's good, but of course I want the css to be included.

b) when I use the method above, every js file fails the renderblocking test.

c) if I move the dynamically appended CSS to inside one of my js files, all the js files fail the renderblocking test.

d) if I move the appended CSS to jquery's document ready function, all the js files fail the renderblocking test.

Given this method is Google's own suggested fix, this a bit frustrating to say the least. Is this simply the size of my css (49kb and minified)? What are the potential solutions?

Comment: I just tried adding in async to the specific js file that dynamically appends the css, and now that js file passes, but all the others don't (and note that if I don't include the css, all the js files pass). Additionally, there is a brief period where the page renders without styling, which looks bad.